# Streaming Raspberry Pi camera to HTML webpage using picamera and Flask

Tags: python, streaming

I am trying to use the [picamera](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/python/README.md) API and Flask to implement a pure Python (live) stream of the continuous JPEG from the Raspberry Pi camera module to display it using a HTML template but I keep getting a "404 not found error"?

I'm a bit inexperienced with this particular subject, apologies in advance.

```
 app.route('/test/')
    def vid():
            with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
                    stream = io.BytesIO()
                    for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, format='jpeg'):

                            stream.truncate()
                            stream.seek(0)

                            if process(stream):
                                break
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
 <img src="{{ url_for('vid') }}"width='950px' height='450px'>
```

Comment: A 404 kind of suggests that you might be using the wrong URL or port number. Can you confirm that you can reach the page if its content is commented out?

Comment: I notice that I've placed the render_template function after the 
        if __name__ == '__main__': app.run(host='169.254.21.3) but im receiving a new error " werkzeug.routing.BuildError,  BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'vid'. Did you mean 'static' instead?" and thanks

Comment: Could you try sticking an @ symbol in front of 'app.route' and rerunning?

Comment: cheers, i should really check my syntax, now my page is showing but the stream isn't appearing?

Comment: You're not returning anything from the vid() function - you're collecting jpegs, but not passing them to the view. Add the import: from flask import send_file , and *outside the for loop*, try adding: return send_file(stream, mimetype='image/jpeg')

Comment: I've managed to show the stream but it automatically stops after showing a image and I couldn't thank you enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some more reading, and don't think your approach will ever function as desired. Miguel Grinberg's article [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask) outlines how to achieve Raspberry Pi camera streaming to Flask, and provides several useful examples. A simple, complete (non-Pi camera) program is provided which shows the use of a generator function and a multi-part response type to achieve animated streaming:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import Camera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

You can see that the `/video-feed` route returns a multipart response type object which is continually generated by the `gen(camera)` function. Without this approach I suspect a static image is all you'll ever see. There is a complete example of a picamera-to-Flask streaming application based on the above tutorial [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-video-streaming).

Comment: just a minor note, but the example is not complete, it requires an additional file (`camera.py`) from the tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

Just change import camera to  picamera. 
You have to install ffpmeg ang mpeg-streamer.
If these two module not work then install uv4l also. After that restart it and it works